# ColdFusion: Using CFINCLUDE in Dreamweaver

Tags: coldfusion, dreamweaver

I am having trouble displaying the `<body>` Data.......`</body>` in "Design" view when I include the `<cfinclude template="file.cfm">` tag in Dreamweaver.  When I include the `<cfinclude template>` tag it only shows the template file, but when I remove it it shows the `<body>` data......`</body>` but without the template in live view?  What could be causing the `<body> some data </body>` not to appear in "design" view with the `<cfinclude template>` tag in code?  Code is below...........

```
<head> <title>Site Name</title>
<cfinclude template="header.cfm"> </head>
<body>
<p><img src="imgname.jpg" alt="" name="Home" width="843"
height="493"    id="Home" /></p> </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit difficult to see exactly what you are trying achieve here but doing a cfinclude is a server side process so you won't see the results of the include in the dreamweaver design view since its not running through the server.  You'll only see it in the live view becuase its being run through the server.

Another thing I see is that you are doing the include in the  of your template.  If the header has html you'd want to put it between the   tags or it won't show up.  CFIncludes are processed inline so the code from your include will be placed right where you have the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you'll find is that most of us here have never used design mode for developing data driven pages.

My guess is that you're hitting some errors in your include that the IDE is stumbling on.

In order to help you, we'll need to see more code and possibly screenshots as this isn't territory that much of us deal with (we mostly play strictly in the codebase).

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver design view is for html/css views of a page - not for rendering the cf.  Try loading/opening the page in a web browser, on your CF server.